# Regex to capture 100 e-mail addresses

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of 1000 e-mail addresses separated by semicolons in Notepad ++, and I am trying to select the first 100 with a regular expression.

My list looks like this:

```
jack@gmail.com; bill@outlook.com; bianca@yahoo.fr;...
```

I used the following regex but it doesn't work (no match found):

```
([^;]+;){100}
```

Comment: Replace the `;` with a newline, then select the first 100 lines?

Comment: `"jack@gmail.com; bill@outlook.com; bianca@yahoo.fr;".match(/([^;]+;){3}/)` works in js. Maybe, whole 100 records are not matched due to line breaks?

Comment: @Jerry ok :-) but I'd be interested to know what's wrong with my regex

Comment: @kirilloid this is a notepad++ question, not js

Comment: @Christophe well, you didn't say what was wrong, but my guess is that it is selecting every email including the semicolon. Or you have less than 100 emails, in which case, you get no matches.

Comment: what version of Notepad++ are you using? its important

Comment: @arserbin3 I just checked, it's version 5.9.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ does not support quantifiers until version 6.0. The problem may simply be updating Notepad++ to the latest version

6.0 Release Notes: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html

Comment: Looks like this is correct. Never suspected it, as v6.0 is over two years old!

Comment: @ach I was working on an older computer, I never thought it would make a difference

Comment: No prob, I held out upgrading for a long time because of TextFX disappearing by default. But I later found out that's easy to add back, through Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Manager

Answer (score 1):

Try this, should work with less than 100 addresses as well (which I expect is your problem):

```
^([^;]+;){1,100}
```

Comment: Is it working for you in notepad++? Not working for me

Comment: Yeah, works fine. This goes without saying, but make sure "Regular Expression" is selected for Search Mode, with Wrap around checked (just to be safe).

Comment: Well, hopefully this regex is useful to someone anyway ;)